# Generating rails model from existing fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 2.3.9. I have a table already and I want to reverse generate a model from there but it gives me "uninitialised constant" error when i run -
rails generate model table_name

trying this - ruby script/generate model table_name 
also gives me errors like-

syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kDO or '{' or '('

Can someone please guide me what could be the issue.

Comment: Cn you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with name `my_records` and there is an `id` primary key on that table, all you need to 'reverse-generate' an active record model from it is to just create the following class:

```
# app/models/my_record.rb
class MyRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Even though it is empty, it would encapsulate the complete active record interface to that table, allowing you to access all the active record magic on that table.

Assuming the following table structure for `my_records` table:

```
create table "my_records" do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "age"
  ..
end
```

the `MyRecord` class would allow you to do things like:

- `MyRecord.count` to see the total number of records in the table
- `MyRecord.where(name: "John")` to find all records with name 'John'
- `MyRecord.create(name: "Helen", age: 25,...)` to create a new record in the table.
- etc.

See [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) and [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more on what capabilities active record provides.

Couple of suggestions on a related note:

1. `rails 2.3.9` is a really old version; if you run into any issues, it will be difficult to find answers; best to start using `rails 4.x` or at least `rails 3.2`.
2. Do spend time on understanding the rails framework; will make it easier in the long run. [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) & [Rails Tutorial book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) are highly recommended resources.